# 16bit RGB to 3 bit RGB

Tags: interface, fpga, vga

I have CMOS camera to capture image and i want to display the captured image on VGA monitor. I am receiving data from CMOS camera in format RGB 565 Like RRRGGGBBB. I have FPGA board with VGA connector RGB (3)pins.how do we convert RGB 565 to single Bit RGB?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really mean "single bit" RGB.
You want to produce single analogue output for each color component - R/G/B.

You'll need to build some kind of DAC outside of FPGA if you want shades. It can be a resistor ladder, for example. Choose its size to reflect the quality you need.

In simplest case you can have just a single resistor in series with R/G/B lines, that will limit your output quality down to a "true single bit" RGB :)

At least let us know what board do you have.